# Specify Worker in Celery

Tags: python, celery, flower

I have two workers:

```
celery worker -l info --concurrency=2 -A o_broker -n main_worker
celery worker -l info --concurrency=2 -A o_broker -n second_worker
```

I am using flower to monitor and receive API requests for these workers:

```
flower -A o_broker
```

to launch these celery workers from an API I use flower per the [docs](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html):

```
curl -X POST -d '{"args":[1,2]}' 'http://localhost:5555/api/task/async-apply/o_broker.add'
```

However, with this POST request it runs the task on either one of the workers. I need to choose to run a specific broker to complete the task.

How do I specify or set this up so I can choose what worker to use for the `add` task? If you have a solution using another API without flower, that would also work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is with separate queues.  Start worker with `-Q first_worker,celery` and the second broker with `-Q second_worker,celery`.  `celery` is the default queue name in `celery`.

Now, when you want to send a task to just the first worker, you can route the task to the `first_worker` queue using celery's [`task_routes` setting](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing).  You treat routing tasks to the `second_worker` queue symmetrically.  You can also [manually route](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing) a particular task call to a certain queue when using `apply_async`, e.g.:

```
add.apply_async(args=(1, 2), queue='first_worker')
```

n.b., last I checked, flower will only monitor one of your queues (by default it's the celery queue).

Comment: Yeah looks like flower only at the celery queue. Whenever I start workers in another queue, flower does not see them. So, I think I will need to create an API layer in nodejs with node-celery. Then, I can route specific queues

Comment: Or is there a way to change the flower queue, because I couldn't find a setting to do so